# Password managers, how do they get the credentials when you press enter?

Tags: passwords, password-management, javascript

I was wondering how password managers (most of the at least) automatically prompt to save my username and password credentials after inserting them into any site.
I mean I am not first putting them into the password manager's (PM) interface, but as soon as you enter the credentials and press enter in any website somehow they are already sent to the PM and ready to be saved when you accept. Can javascript have that much access? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's simple, in web whenever a page is created for login or for signup there  are few things that kept in mind.

1-The user input is taken in forms. `<form>...<form>`

2-Variables are created to take your input,that depends on what are the rules for inputs.

3-In web a tag `<input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" data-testid="royal_pass">` in this snippet the  `type = "password"` 
tells you are going to enter password

So whenever you are going to fill a login page the browser detects and asks you to save the password.Then Browser checks for username, the tag is also used for user name. Basically you can say that input works as a variable, whose name is `"pass"` to take your input and proceed.